# Cannot figure out how to finish hangman date signing

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, methods

display a double 3 time method for tracking analysis with frameworks
we need to find the x for y
and describe why it happeneds that way
do not quote for 32 x 8. Most of the If the player guess a letter which exists in the word, the script writes it in all its correct positions.  The player has 10 turns to guess the word. You can easily customize the game by changing the variables.live coding demo portion of the course and showing the process of coding a

```
#importing the time module
import time

#welcoming the user
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")

print "Hello, " + name, "Time to play hangman!"

print "
"

#wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)

print "Start guessing..."
time.sleep(0.5)

#here we set the secret
word = "secret"

#creates an variable with an empty value
guesses = ''

#determine the number of turns
turns = 10

# Create a while loop

#check if the turns are more than zero
while turns > 0:         

# make a counter that starts with zero
failed = 0             

# for every character in secret_word    
for char in word:      

# see if the character is in the players guess
    if char in guesses:    

    # print then out the character
        print char,    

    else:

    # if not found, print a dash
        print "_",     
   
    # and increase the failed counter with one
        failed += 1    

# if failed is equal to zero

# print You Won
if failed == 0:        
    print "
You won"  

# exit the script
    break              

print

# ask the user go guess a character
guess = raw_input("guess a character:") 

# set the players guess to guesses
guesses += guess                    

# if the guess is not found in the secret word
if guess not in word:  

 # turns counter decreases with 1 (now 9)
    turns -= 1        

# print wrong
    print "Wrong
"    

# how many turns are left
    print "You have", + turns, 'more guesses' 

# if the turns are equal to zero
    if turns == 0:           

    # print "You Lose"
        print "You Lose
"
```

Answer (score 1):

The mainloop is a function of the root window, so you should assign a name to it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD'
    converter = MikesMagicalConverter(url)
    app = App(converter)     # Assing a name to root window
    app.mainloop()           # Run root window mainloop
```

When you create the button you should provide a reference to the master:

```
buttonExample = tk.Button(self,    # Provide reference to master
      text="Create new window",
      command=lambda:self.currency_converter.createNewWindow(self))  # Pass reference
buttonExample.pack()
```

The command argument is a bit trickier; the class `MikesMagicalConverter` is not a widget and does not inherit from tkiner so you'll have to pass a reference to use as master to the `Toplevel` window.

You must provide a `self` parameter to the `createNewWindow()` method.

```
def createNewWindow(self, master): 
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(master)   # Using reference as master 
    labelExample = tk.Label(newWindow, text = "New Window")
    buttonExample = tk.Button(newWindow, text = "New Window button")
    labelExample.pack()
    buttonExample.pack()
```

In general: many of your lines are way to long, makes the code hard to read.

With those changes the code will still generate error, but the button and Toplevel window pops up. I'm thinking you might rather separate the currency calculations from the GUI code.